# nginx image rewriting

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

is it possible to rewrite images? image store in /very/big/path/1.jpg , i want /img/1.jpg
how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its easier to use the search here at first.

[Rewrite1](https://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters)
[Rewrite2](https://serverfault.com/questions/139579/nginx-subdomain-rewrite)

type: "nginx rewrite" to the search.

And there are many more posts where you can see how redirecting work with nginx ;).

Edit:

RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ very/big/path/$1

something like this should work.

Comment: i need that img  runs as php

Comment: ok and where is the problem? You should edit your question and write it more detailed. On the sites that i have posted you can see how the rewrite works ;) when you searh here you will find an answer i am sure... that were only 2 question from many.