# Nginx rewrite to eliminate "www" not working

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, configuration

I've looked at many [SE threads](https://serverfault.com/questions/139579/nginx-subdomain-rewrite) and done various [google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+config+set+rewrite) and can't figure out why i can't redirect `www.mysite.com` to `mysite.com` on my nginx server.

The 1st server block does the `http://mysite.info` -> `https://mysite.info` redirect as you'd expect. So i'm not sure why the 2nd server block isn't doing the same for the `www.mysite.info` -> `mysite.info`.

Here's the relevant part of my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.info;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    server_name www.mysite.info;
    rewrite ^ https://mysite.info$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen   443;
    ssl    on;
    server_name mysite.info;
    # other directives, handling PHP, etc.
}
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You're redirecting to `$server_name`, which is `www.mysite.info` in the second `server` block - so all that's doing is redirecting to HTTPS, not changing the host.

```
rewrite ^ https://mysite.info$request_uri? permanent;
```

That'll handle the change in host as well as the change to HTTPS.

If you wanted the redirect to be protocol agnostic, a better approach would be:

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://mysite.info$request_uri? permanent;
```

On recent versions of nginx, this works as well (and should be a bit faster):

```
return 301 $scheme://mysite.info$request_uri;
```

Comment: Also, [according to NGiNX's documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls), it is better practice to use `return 301` instead of `rewrite`.

Comment: @Shane, sorry I made a copy/paste mistake. My 2nd directive is as you've written in your answer. Please see my updated question. Thoughts on why that doesn't work?

Comment: @Shane, also how use the `return 301` given my 3 `server{}` blocks? I've just tried a couple things but get this error: ` invalid number of arguments in "return" directive` when I try to restart my server.

Comment: @timpeterson Do you have any _other_ `server` blocks?

Comment: none that i know of, i'm a novice as you can tell, just did the `sudo apt-get install nginx /php` on my ubuntu machine and now here I am, are there other files I need to look at?

Comment: I have 2 include statements in my `http{}` block that were there by default: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`. Should I comment these out?